# Generating a self-signed certificate with iOS Security.framework?

Tags: ios, security, x509

Is it possible, and if so how? I'm working with a protocol that needs a client certificate, so I want to generate one once and store it in the keychain for future use.

I'm currently using the Security framework to generate key pairs via SecKeyGeneratePair, but is there any way to package up that generated public key in an X.509 certificate and add it with the private key to create a new SecIdentity? I figure there should be a way since the Security framework is supposed to be the same on iOS and Mac, and Keychain Access on the Mac can generate self signed certificates.

OpenSSL is an option, but I'd much rather use the built in Security framework if at all possible.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like this isn't currently possible with the Security framework, so I'll have to use OpenSSL. Info: https://devforums.apple.com/message/652850 Bug: http://www.openradar.me/12938395

Answer (score 5):

Aye - it is (and bloody painful). Below is the code I am using. It signs with the keys generated in a SecKeyGeneratePair() (and hence in the keychain/outside reach).

The crux for me in cracking this was finding out that SecKeyRawSign
only liked SHA1.

Feel free to DM me if you want to take some existing running code off my hand, clean it up, add docs and then get it on github with a nice Apache License for all to enjoy.

```
(NSData *)signCSR:(NSData *)derCSR forDays:(double)days NIDstToKeep:(NSSet *)nidsToAllow 
{
    const unsigned char * ptr;
    NSUInteger len;

    // Gather the details for the CA cert (my cert) from
    // OSX.
    //
    X509 * x509_mycert = NULL;
    SecIdentityRef identityRef = [self secIdentityRef];
    if (!identityRef)
        return nil;

    SecCertificateRef certificateRef = [self secCertificateRef];
    if (!certificateRef)
        return nil;

    CFDataRef certAsDer = SecCertificateCopyData(certificateRef);
    if (!certAsDer)
        return nil;

    // Jump over the fence to OpenSSL  - and create
    // an X509 version.
    //
    ptr = CFDataGetBytePtr(certAsDer);
    len = CFDataGetLength(certAsDer);

    if (!(d2i_X509(&x509_mycert, &ptr, len)))
        return nil;

    // And likewise for the CSR.
    //
    ptr = (const unsigned char *)[derCSR bytes];
    len = [derCSR length];

    X509_REQ *req = NULL;
    if (!(d2i_X509_REQ(&req, &ptr, len)))
        return nil;

    // Copy the CSR into a an actual x509 tenative
    // structure; i.e. the cert we'll issue signed.
    //
    X509 * x509_to_sign = X509_new();

    assert(X509_set_subject_name(x509_to_sign,req->req_info->subject));
    assert(X509_set_issuer_name(x509_to_sign, X509_get_subject_name(x509_mycert)));

    EVP_PKEY * pubkey_csr = X509_REQ_get_pubkey(req);
    X509_set_pubkey(x509_to_sign,pubkey_csr);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pubkey_csr);

    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509_to_sign),0L);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509_to_sign),(long)floor(60*60*24*days));

    if (nidsToAllow && [nidsToAllow count]) {
        // Faily blindly copy all known extensions.
        //
        for(int i = X509_get_ext_count(x509_to_sign); i > 0; i--) {
            X509_EXTENSION * ext = X509_get_ext(x509_to_sign,i-i);
            int nid = OBJ_obj2nid(ext->object);
            if ([nidsToAllow containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nid]]) {
                // NSLog(@"Keeping %s at %d", OBJ_nid2sn(nid),i-i);
                continue;
            }
            // NSLog(@"Killing %s at %d", OBJ_nid2sn(nid),i-1);
            X509_delete_ext(x509_to_sign, i-i);
        }
    } else {
        // wipe them all.
        //
        while (X509_get_ext_count(x509_to_sign) > 0) {
            X509_delete_ext(x509_to_sign, 0);
        }
    };

    // Set a random serial.
    //
    ASN1_INTEGER *bs = ASN1_INTEGER_new();
    long rnd = 0;
    if (!(RAND_bytes((unsigned char *)&rnd, sizeof(rnd))))
        return nil;

    rnd = labs(rnd);
    ASN1_INTEGER_set(bs, rnd);

    if (!((X509_set_serialNumber(x509_to_sign,bs))))
        return nil;

    ASN1_INTEGER_free(bs);

    // Force v3
    //
    X509V3_CTX ctx2;
    X509_set_version(x509_to_sign,2); /* version 3 certificate */
    X509V3_set_ctx(&ctx2, x509_mycert, x509_to_sign, NULL, NULL, 0);

    // Pull in additional x509v3 sections.
    //
    if (DBA) {
       assert(X509V3_set_nconf(&ctx2, conf));
       assert(X509V3_EXT_add_nconf(conf, &ctx2, section, x509_to_sign));
    }
    // Specify signature type.
    //
    x509_to_sign->cert_info->signature->algorithm = OBJ_nid2obj(NID_sha1WithRSAEncryption);

    // Construct the ASN.1 blob which contains all the information
    // we are going to sign.
    //
    const ASN1_ITEM * it = ASN1_ITEM_rptr(X509_CINF);
    unsigned char *buf_in=NULL;
    ASN1_VALUE * asn = (ASN1_VALUE *)(x509_to_sign->cert_info);
    int inl = ASN1_item_i2d(asn,&buf_in, it);

    // Small area to hold the signature on the SHA1 hash.
    //
    size_t sigLen = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey);
    uint8_t * sig = (uint8_t *)malloc(sigLen * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void*)sig, 0, sigLen);

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    // IPhone Way of doing it - where we need to construct the
    // SHA1 of the 'to sign' area ourselves. As SecKeyRawSign
    // does not seem to handly anything beyond a SHA1.
    //
    NSData * buffToSign = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf_in length:inl];
    NSData * buffSha1ToSign = [buffToSign sha1];

    size_t sigLenUsed = sigLen;

    OSStatus status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey, kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1, [buffSha1ToSign bytes], [buffSha1ToSign length], sig, &sigLenUsed);
    assert(status == noErr);
    assert(sigLenUsed == sigLen);

#else
    // MacOSX offical way of doing this - which seems to do the SHA1 fun,
    // padding and games deeper down; and where we simply pass the blob.
    //
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    SecTransformRef signer = SecSignTransformCreate(privateKey, &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); assert(0); };

    NSData * blockToSign = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf_in length:inl];
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer, kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
                             (__bridge CFTypeRef) blockToSign, &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); assert(0); };

    CFDataRef signature = SecTransformExecute(signer, &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); assert(0); };

    assert(sigLen == CFDataGetLength(signature));
    bcopy(CFDataGetBytePtr(signature), sig, sigLen);
#endif

    // Wrap up the rest of the block with the bits and bobs needed to
    // create a valid ASN1 block to share as a PEM or DER. Which most
    // crucially is about copying the just created signature into it.
    //
    x509_to_sign->sig_alg->algorithm = OBJ_nid2obj(NID_sha1WithRSAEncryption);
    x509_to_sign->signature->data = sig;
    x509_to_sign->signature->length = sigLen;
    x509_to_sign->signature->flags&= ~(ASN1_STRING_FLAG_BITS_LEFT|0x07);
    x509_to_sign->signature->flags|=ASN1_STRING_FLAG_BITS_LEFT;

    unsigned char * derbuff = NULL;
    int derlen = i2d_X509(x509_to_sign, &derbuff);

    NSData * signedDer = [NSData dataWithBytes:derbuff length:derlen];

    free(sig);
    OPENSSL_free(x509_to_sign);
    OPENSSL_free(x509_mycert);

    return signedDer;
}
```

Note that I stripped out some proprietary/non-public bits - so above will likely miss a few CFReleases() and sundry.

Comment: I'm already capable of doing this with OpenSSL, with less code too, I was looking for a way with just the Security framework. This also relies on the assumption that SecCertificateCopyData returns DER data, which eskimo1 on the Apple Developer forums has indicated could change.

Comment: Ok - been able to use Sec*() et.al. with proper keyref's on iOS just fine to generate self signed, generate requests and to sign such request (a ad-hoc p2p based 'meet in physical space and sign' app using chirps). And do so without the app being aware of the actual sensitive crypto material. But have not found a way to not surround the SecKeyGeneratePair/SecSign/etc with a lot of openSSL to get shape the extensions and similar ASN1/DER mangling - at the very least for the serial/DNs. For which there is no Sec* alternative. Feel free to drop me a mail on dirkx(at)webweaving(dot)org.